# how to make changes from another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm new to Flutter and I need help with logic part for my project so if this question doesn't belong in SOF, please let me know.

So I have stacks of cards in one screen and I want to control those cards from another screen but I'm not really sure how to implement and the logic behind it so can somebody help me?.

so the idea is, The user can view stacks of cards in Home Screen but they can't reorder their position, if the user want to do that than he have to go to Reorder Screen.

Basic idea of the app will look like

```
    Home Screen
    .......................

    Card 1
    Card 2 
    Card 3

    //All cards are stack together

    Reorder Screen. 
    .........................

    Button 1 (syn to Card 1)
    Button 2 (syn to Card 2)
    Button 3 (syn to Card 3)

    it will appear in this order but the user can move their position 
by drag and drop and this will also change the order of the Cards in Home Screen too,
```

[image]

I understand that It'll be very difficult without looking any code but please let me know how you going approach to implement this feature if you were asked to do it.

Any suggestion or help on the logic part will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called state management. You state is the data which can change. The simplest option is to pass variables from the card screen to the button screen. The button screen would then make changes to this state, and pass it back. You can do this with just stateful widgets and `setState`. For more complicated state, you will need to use a more advanced system like [the bloc pattern](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) or [providers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

For this example, you could pass the list to the list to the button screen from the card screen. The button screen modifies this list, then you use setState to apply changes to the screen. Be aware of widget [keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc) when changing the order of items in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is a **state management** solution. There is a lot of them, with each their pros and cons. I *(and the Flutter team)* would suggest **Provider**.

Basically, your `Provider` would hold the cards data list and a function to reorder it.

Then, both the screens would depend on that data (using a `Consumer`).

And the reorder screen would call something like `context.read<YourProvider>().reorder(oldIndex, newIndex)` to reorder the list.

Take a look at this for further details : [Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

If you want to get informed about other SM solutions : [List of state management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)